# QML: How to delete a global QSGTexture object?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have QQuickItem derived class (MyItem) which just draws a texture (QSGTexture). Because all MyItem's drawing the same texture I have shared one QSGTexture instance between all of them. This instance is created on first access:

```
QSGTexture *MyItem::getGlobalTexture()
{
    static auto tex = window->createTextureFromImage(QImage{s_textureName});
    return tex;
}
```

Everyting fine with it but I want somehow to delete this texture on app destruction.

My first idea was to set some parent to it and I have chosen a QQuickWindow, but it is not possible because they live on different threads:

```
window - mainThread, tex - SGRenderThread
```

Another way is to delete it in MyApp destructor, but this call will also be from the *mainThread* and *SGRenderThread* may be already deleted.

One more idea is to use `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit` signal with a `QueuedConnection` type, so the deleting will happen on the `SGRenderThread` if it still exists and will not be drawing any more frames.

What is the best and right way to delete a global QSGTexture object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the following solution what is actually the third idea from the question and it seems to work for both threaded and not threaded Scene Graph

```
QSGTexture *MyItem::getGlobalTexture(QQuickWindow *window)
{
    static QSGTexture *texture = [window]{
        auto tex = window->createTextureFromImage(QImage{s_textureName});
        //will delete the texture on the GSthread 
        QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, tex, [tex]{ tex->deleteLater(); });
        return tex;
    }();
    return texture;
}
```